# Item space between in menu item is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspmenu-control

I'd like give a space between asp.net menu item. Hence, I tried with the `staticmenuitemstyle` and `horizontalpadding="10"` attribute which was suggested by some other post in SO. But, It's not working.

```
<staticmenuitemstyle horizontalpadding="10" />
```

Please let me know how can I give space between menu item ?

My code ::

```
 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
           EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
           BackColor="#F7F6F3" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" 
           Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#7C6F57" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
      <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
      <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
      <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
      <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
      <staticmenuitemstyle horizontalpadding="10" />
      <Items>
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/WebPages/Default.aspx"  Text="Support1">
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/WebPages/Default2.aspx"  Text="Support2">
      </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using? The Menu control renders as an `ul` in 4.0 and as a `table` in previous versions. With that being said, you can control the spacing via CSS accordingly.

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4.0.  @juanreyesv please let me know how can i handle in CSS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to achieve that

In your code you have asigned the `CssClass` attribute to your `Menu` control. Make use of that CSS class called "menu" and override it in your page (you can move it later to a css file). So add this to your page in the `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .menu li ~ li
    {
        padding-left: 100px; /* selects every <li> element that are preceded by a <li> element. */
        list-style:none;
    }

    .menu ul > li:first-child
    {
        font-size:20px;/* this one will select the first element of your menu */
    }
</style>
```

Please note that I added the `.menu ul > li:first-child` selector so you will not get a left padding on the first element of the menu, I just changed the `font-size` to give you an example of the control that CSS selectors provide. You can remove it if you like.

Hope this helps you